# How to run code only when iframe loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, delay

I have been battling with this issue for a few days now and finally found a partial solution but I think it could be improved.

In my project, I have a series of `iframe`s that contain videos. When a link is clicked are displayed with a slide transition and when the link is clicked again the video stops and the `span` containing the `iframe` is hidden also with a transition.

This is achieved by adding and removing a css class of "open" that has a height and a transition in it. In addition to this I have an event listener that collapses the containing span also when the video finishes. All this works fine and to save time I am not posting the code.

The issue I was having was with slow page loading times, so I removed the `src` attribute for the `iframe`s from the html and moved it to my js file and assigned it only after the click is performed. This wasn't working and I realised I needed the `iframe` to fully load before running the rest of the code inside the "click" method. So I delayed this part of the code by 100ms.

All this works, but I feel it would be better to have the rest of the code run not after a 100ms lapse but when the `iframe` is loaded (in case page viewed by slower computers). Not sure how to do this.

Here is the code as it stands now:

```
var player;
var frame = $("#frame");


frame.bind("load", function () {
    player = $(this).contents().find("#myVid");
    player.on('ended', function () {
        frame.removeClass("open");
    });
});

$("#clickableLink").click(function(){


        if (frame.hasClass("open")) {   

            frame.removeClass("open");
            frame.contents().find('#myVid').get(0).pause();

        } else {

            function delayed(){

                frame.addClass("open");
                frame.contents().find('#myVid').get(0).play();

            }
            frame.attr("src","iframe.html");
            setTimeout(delayed, 100);
        }


});
```

Fairly new to development so I am looking for the simplest way to do this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use the ``onload`` listener on the ``iframe``?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a super simple example of calling code when the `iframe` has loaded. Check out the `onload` attribute of the `iframe` tag:

```html
<head>
  <script>
  function frameLoaded() {
    alert('frame loaded!');
  };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe id="frame" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames" onload="frameLoaded(this)" />
</body>
```

Comment: I have the issue that it's not fired in latest firefox when the url is incorrect. I read [here](https://javascript.info/onload-onerror) that `The only exception is <iframe>: for historical reasons it always triggers load, for any load completion, even if the page is not found.` Which in case of firefox would be incorrect behaviour.

Comment: eferenceError: frameLoaded is not defined
    at HTMLIFrameElement.onload
what am I doing wrong  ?